# Wireless syncing between PC and android phone but with a preview

Tags: android, file-synchronization

Looking for something like [bittorrent sync](https://www.getsync.com/) which syncs files wirelessly between PC and android phone BUT with a preview before syncing like [FreeFileSync](http://www.freefilesync.org/).

FreeFileSync is great in that you can see what is going to happen before you sync and if necessary change actions for certain folders - but it doesn't work wirelessly (as far as I know). It's also great in that it handles renamed and moved files/folders (usually) without re-copying them over.

Bittorent Sync is great in that it syncs wirelessly between pc and phone but sometimes it gets things wrong and there are lots of conflicts. For instance, sometimes the timestamps are out by a few minutes for some reason and it tries to re-copy everything over.
It also seems to go very slowly occasionally for no reason.

Comment: Not having a preview, but worth trying is *FolderSync* (which is what I use with my Android devices). Supports a load of protocols. Maybe it works better for you than BT, so you don't really need that preview.

Comment: I use FolderSync already and actually have the full version, but it struggles with syncing large amounts of files. I don't think the phone should be doing the syncing, it's just too slow and uses up battery.

Comment: Ah, OK then: your use-case is a bit different than mine. I don't care about "slow" and "battery" here (as sync is always done nightly with the device connected to the charger, thanks to *Tasker's* help), and probably don't have that large amount of files. Well, was worth a thought at least :)

Answer (score 2):

### [AndFTPPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftppro) + [Bitvise SHH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server)

[AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp) is an FTP/SFTP/SCP client for Android. It allows you to browse and copy files between your Android device and PC over your home network. AndFTPPro comes with a few extra useful features including sync with preview. First it creates a report of the differences between the two folders, then shows a confirmation dialog. See image below (click for full size version)

[image]

You can use AndFTPPro with any FTP server on your PC. I personally find Bitvise Server the most convenient. It's easy to install and configure. More detailed instructions can be found [on this page](https://www.bitvise.com/configuring-ssh-server-for-sftp). Use it to set a virtual account, whose credentials you input in AndFTPPro as log-in info. Make sure to enable the "allow file transfer" setting in Bitvise Server, and ensure that the virtual account has read and/or write access to the target folder.

Bitvise Server is free for non-commercial usage. AndFTPPro costs 4.77€ or your regional equivalent